# I am getting an error message like 'Trace Back Error' while i try to enable a addon in blender

Tags: rigging, add-on, mixamo

I am Using Blender 4.0 and i installed Mixamo Auto rigging addon in it. but when i try to enable the addon, an error message pops saying "TRACEBACK" error. the addon is showing in the preference addon menu, but i am unable to enable it. Please someone help me in solving this issue. I have attached [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zscq.png) of the situation i am encountering.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look as if it's been updated to cope with Blender 4's APIs yet. There's a thread [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/mixamo-discussions/mixamo-addon-not-working-on-blender-4-0/td-p/14242570) on the Adobe Community forum.